# Restangular: Make request fail when 200 OK response contains specific payload

Tags: angularjs, restangular

I have URL I'm using that gives a 200 OK status and a JSON payload of {error: "Invalid user"} when you do not provide a correct user on a GET request. When using this URL with Restangular, I would prefer this resulted in an error so I can handle errors in the typical way with promises, otherwise my code is going to be very messy. How would I do this?

Comment: Where is your code? Anyway, Http result is depend on your backend code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify an an response interceptor like this:

```
app.config(function(RestangularProvider) {

    // add a response intereceptor
    RestangularProvider.addResponseInterceptor(function(data, operation, what, url, response, deferred) {
    // check the response if it contains error or not.
      if (typeof(response.error) !== 'undefined') {
            alert('Your authentication Fail!');
            return false;
        };
      return response;
    });

});
```